# Update total variable when quantity is changed

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble updating the total when I change the "Complete E-Book" product quantity. When I first set the quantity and add it to basket it shows the correct total within the basket but when I change the quantity it adds on to the previous total. Overall I want to be able to add multiple products to the basket total (reason for `x += p2Total` (x var is what holds the total - Line 86) but while allowing for the Quantity of the product to be changed and then updated in the total.

[Codepen Here >](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWzJNb)
Products in question are the top 2

JS:

```
// JQuery Functions for NavBar - Class Toggle

(function() {
  $('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.bar').toggleClass('animate');
  })
})();

(function() {
  $('.hamburger-menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.bar2').toggleClass('ApprDown');
  })
})();

/* 

START OF BASKET 
START OF BASKET


*/

// Get access to add to basket basket button
var addToBasket = document.querySelector('.atbb');
addToBasket.addEventListener('click', P1);

// Formatter simply formats the output into a currceny format istead of a general number format. This is using the ECMAScript Internationalization API 

var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'GBP',
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
});

var totalBasket
var discountLimit = 10
var discount = 3.50
var x = 0.00
// One big function with different condtions based on the differnt products and then simply concatinate the values where needed
function P1() {
  var y = document.getElementById("p1Quant").value;
  if (+y > discountLimit) {

    var z = 15.000
    x = parseFloat(+y) * parseFloat(+z); // + will convert the vars into Numbers etc
    document.getElementById("BasketSumData").innerHTML = ("Sub Total: ") + formatter.format(x) + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("<div class='strike'>Plus £3.50 Delivery</div>") + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("Total: ") + formatter.format(x)

//     Jquery Notificaiton  

 var truckVar = document.getElementById("truck");
    truckVar.setAttribute("class", "animateTruck");




  } else if (+y <= 0) {

    document.getElementById("BasketSumData").innerHTML = ("Sub Total: ") + formatter.format(0) + ("<br/>") + ("Total: ") + formatter.format(0)

  } else {

    var z = 15.000
    var s = 15.000
    x = parseFloat(+y) * parseFloat(+z) + 3.50
    var sub = parseFloat(+y) * parseFloat(+s)
    document.getElementById("BasketSumData").innerHTML = ("Sub Total: ") + formatter.format(sub) + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("Plus £3.50 Delivery") + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("Total: ") + formatter.format(x)

  }
}



var addToBasket2 = document.querySelector('.atbb2');
addToBasket2.addEventListener('click', P2);

function P2() {

    p2Total = 0.00
  var y = document.getElementById("p2Quant").value;


    var p2 = 8.00
   var p2Total = parseFloat(+y) * parseFloat(+p2); // + will convert the vars into Numbers etc
   // var totalBasket = + x + x  // javascript add value onto set var

   x += p2Total // Append the amount to the basket 

   document.getElementById("BasketSumData").innerHTML = ("Sub Total: ") + formatter.format(x) + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("<div class='strike'>Plus £3.50 Delivery</div>") + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("Total: ") + formatter.format(x)


  if (+y <= 0) {

    p2Total = 0.00

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add the value to x, add x and p2Total into a new temporary value that is scoped to the function itself and use that.

```
var tmp_total = x + p2Total;
document.getElementById("BasketSumData").innerHTML = ("Sub Total: ") + formatter.format(tmp_total) + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("<div class='strike'>Plus £3.50 Delivery</div>") + ("<br/>") + ("<hr />") + ("Total: ") + formatter.format(tmp_total)
```

Comment: Ok thanks that's fixed it for the Complete E-Book Product but now if I add that product to the basket first and then add the top product (Printed Book) after it doesn't add together in the basket?
 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EmvQoK?editors=0010